# Amazon Kinesis - Identify Step Timeout

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-kpl

Trying to create a Kinesis Analytics query to alert when a step in a process has taken too long (or died and not moved on).

I have a steam of data that contains status updates as a multi-step process moves from step to step. I am trying to write a query that can identify when the next step hasn't happened within a specific amount of time (aka timed out).  Specifically, I would like to know when a single ProcessID doesn't move from "Started" to "Running" within 5 minutes.

I know how to do this in a Database, but it gets confusing when the timescale is constantly moving.  Any help you can provide is much appreciated!

**My events have three attributes:** 
ProcessID - Integer 
Status - String ("Started", "Running", or "Complete") 
HappenedOn - Datetime (e.g. 2017-10-02 15:17:00)

**How I would do this in Database (non Kinesis)**

In SQL I would use join the event table to itself using a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but can't figure out how to do this in a real time query situation.

```
#This will show me the start events that don't have a corresponding 'running' event

SELECT * FROM events as F 
LEFT OUTER JOIN events as S on F.PROCESSID = S.PROCESSID AND S.STATUS = 'running'
WHERE  F.STATUS = 'start' AND S.STATUS IS NULL;
```

**Solution so far in Kinesis**
This query saves and runs, but doesn't give me what I am looking for.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM" (E1PROCESSID integer, 
E1STATUS varchar(7), E1HAPPENED varchar(32), E2PROCESSID integer, 
E2STATUS varchar(7), E2HAPPENED varchar(32) );

CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "STREAM_PUMP" AS INSERT INTO "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM"

SELECT F.PROCESSID, F.STATUS, F.HAPPENED, S.PROCESSID, S.STATUS, S.HAPPENED
FROM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001" OVER (RANGE INTERVAL '5' MINUTE PRECEDING) AS F 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001"  AS S
ON F.PROCESSID = S.PROCESSID AND S.STATUS = 'running'
WHERE F.STATUS = 'start' AND S.STATUS IS NULL;
```

Even if I could get the above query to work, I need Kinesis to only look for corresponding events (or the lack of them) 5 minutes after the HAPPENED value (e.g. need to do a DATEDIFF between the current datetime and HAPPENED).  Any advice on how to add this would be appreciated.

Also, I feel like I need to use FOLLOWING not PRECEDING, but the SQL parser won't let me (and I can see why).  I am also confused on which stream join to add the OVER window to...LEFT?  RIGHT?  BOTH?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: For reference Amazon documentation talks about using an OUTER JOIN in [this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/stream-joins-concepts.html) but every time I try to use  FOLLOWING instead of PRECEDING the SQL validator gets mad at me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Drools by creating the following rules:

```
declare EventA
  @role( event )
end

declare EventB
  @role( event ) 
end

rule "Timeout EventA"
when
  $a : EventA()
  not(exists(EventB(this after[0,5m] $a)))
then
  insertLogical(new TimeoutA($a.id));
end
```

You can author Drools Kinesis Analytics with [this service](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B075MDR5DC)

Comment: Wow!  This is great.  I knew Drools could do this but didn't know that there was a AWS Kinesis option in the market place.  Can't thank you enough for the help!

Comment: @TimMerkel: if you find it helpful, please mark as an answer